# UPDATE statement on Access database fails silently under pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, syntax-error, pyodbc

I have a problem with a simple UPDATE statement. I wrote a Python tool which creates a lot of UPDATE statements and after creating them I want to execute them on my Access database but it doesn't work This is one statement for example:

```
UPDATE FCL_B_COVERSHEET_A SET BRANCH = 0 WHERE OBJ_ID = '1220140910132011062005';
```

The statement syntax is not the problem. I tested it and it works.

This next code snippet shows the initialization for the connect object.

```
strInputPathMDB = "C:\\Test.mdb"
DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}';
con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={0};Dbq={1};Uid={2};Pwd={3};'.format(DRV,strInputPathMDB,"administrator",""))
```

After that I wrote a method which execute one SQL statement

```
def executeSQLStatement(conConnection, strSQL):
        arcpy.AddMessage(strSQL)
        cursor = conConnection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(strSQL)
        conConnection.commit()
```

and if I execute this code everything seems to work - no error message or anything like that - but also the data is not updated and I don't know what I'm doing wrong ...

```
for strSQL in sqlStateArray:
    executeSQLStatement(con, strSQL)
con.close()
```

I hope you understand what my problem is. Thanks for your help.

Chris

Comment: Is your database file really in C:\ (the root folder of the C: drive)?

Comment: Yes it is. But I also tried in "D:\\Test.mdb" and it doesnt work.

Comment: Try putting the .mdb file in a place where you know everyone has unrestricted read/write privileges, like "Public Documents", and see if that helps. Your code is essentially correct, so I suspect a permissions issue on the folder in which the .mdb is stored.

Comment: Thank you very much. I put the mdb file in a public folder and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that the .mdb file was in the root folder of the C: drive. Root folders often restrict normal users to read-only access so the database file was being opened as read-only. Moving the .mdb file to a public folder solved the problem.